# how to parse json with various arrays

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file that looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "aaa",
    "idMembers": [
      "David",
      "Mary"
    ],
    "actions": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "date": "2019-08-28"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "date": "2019-08-29"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "date": "2019-08-30"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "bbb",
    "idMembers": [
      "Mar",
      "Alex"
    ],
    "actions": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "date": "2019-07-28"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "date": "2019-07-29"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to obtain a result like:

```
["David", "Mary", "1", "2019-08-28"]
["David", "Mary", "2", "2019-08-29"]
["David", "Mary", "3", "2019-08-30"]
["Mar", "Alex", "1", "2019-07-28"]
["Mar", "Alex", "2", "2019-07-29"]
```

I tried:

```
jq -c '.[] | [ .idMembers[], .actions[].id, .actions[].date] '
```

But results are:

```
["David", "Mary", "1", "2", "3", "2019-08-28", "2019-08-29", "2019-08-30"]
["Mar", "Alex", "1", "2", "2019-07-28", "2019-07-29"]
```

I would like do someting like:

```
jq -c '.[] | .idMembers[], .actions[] | [ .id, .date] '
```

but it return me

jq: error (at :1268): Cannot index string with string "id"

Is possible to do something similar to this?

```
jq -c '.[] | .actions[] | [.idMembers[], .id, .date] '
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array out of each object under `actions` and add it to `idMembers`.

```
.[] | .idMembers + (.actions[] | map(.))
```

`map(.)` can also be written as `[.[]]`. For clarification, above is the same as:

```
.[] | .idMembers + (.actions[0] | map(.)),
      .idMembers + (.actions[1] | map(.)),
      .idMembers + (.actions[2] | map(.)),
                            ...
      .idMembers + (.actions[n] | map(.))
```

where `n` is the number of elements in `actions`.

Comment: Thank for your response :) ! Do you know how can I select in map(.) only .id? I tried 
```
.[] | .idMembers + (.actions[] | map(.id))
```
But doesn't work

Comment: @Joakin in that case you would need to replace `map(.)` with `[.id]`.